# read a CSV file from post request

Tags: python, django, csv, django-rest-framework

i am trying to get read some data from a CSV file but when I try read the file with the folwing method I get the error

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

```
def post(self, request):
        serializer = MosqueFileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            file =pd.read_csv(request.FILES['file'])
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and when i try to open the file i get another error

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

```
def post(self, request):
        serializer = MosqueFileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            file =pd.read_csv(open(request.FILES['file']))
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

so can someone help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/_modules/django/core/files/base/#File), the file pointer of an `InMemoryUploadedFile` object is at its `.file` attribute. The `open` function returns the `InMemoryUploadedFile` object itself.

Also `open` is a member function of `InMemoryUploadedFile` instance. So instead of `open(request.FILES['file'])`

I suggest you try

```
request.FILES['file'].open()
file = pd.read_csv(request.FILES['file'].file)
```

Edit: fixed the wrong call in previous version

Comment: I tried but i still get the error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Comment: @Halim what happens when you print type(request.FILES['file'].file), request.FILES['file'].name, request.FILES['file'].mode

Comment: Fixed my answer. So it is actually open(...) throw this exception

Comment: when i print  type(request.FILES['file'].file)i get type <class '_io.BytesIO'>, print(request.FILES['file'].name) i get the right file name,
but print(request.FILES['file'].mode) get error AttributeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'mode'

Comment: when i try open(request.FILES['file']) i sill get error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Comment: @Halim instead of using open(request.FILES['file']) you shall use request.FILES['file'].open(). I have edited my answer to show that too.

Comment: i tried now with request.FILES['file'].open() but i get error ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: it works right now, the problem was i did not use import pandas as pd in Views.py
actually, i was using the file in another function and it was working but when i start using aws S3 i have to change the path but i forget to import pandas when i was test the file